# How to redirect AWS Amplify when index.html is in a folder

Tags: html, amazon-web-services

My index.html file is not in the main folder but in a subfolder called "Pages" how can I make the AWS server go to the index while its in the folder

Using the redirect tool and the fixed path of /Pages/index.html didnt work and resulted in a failed page.

Answer (score 0):

Used the redirect tool better and changed the rule type to 404 redirect and it worked wonderfully

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).